# How can I create 2 different layouts on same page with channel entry list and single channel entry?

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, templates, channel, entries

I am creating a page in my site with a list of entries under 1 channel.

I have the template structure as follows:

- collections/ss14
- collections/aw14
- collections/index

The ss14/aw14 templates pull in data from the channel with all their entries listed here is my template so far:

```
<div id="container" class="collection">
{if segment_4 == "ss14"}
<div id="gallery-t-group" class="rsMinW">
<h1>this is the list view</h1>
   {exp:channel:entries channel="ss14" dynamic="yes" url_title="{segment_4}"}
      <div class="portfolio load-slide">
        <img data-rsh="400" class="rsImg {dimension} root" src="{images}{url}{/images}" alt="{long_name}" />
            <div class="rsTmb"><img class="{dimension}" src="{images}{url}{/images}"></div>
            <input type="hidden" value="{path={site_short_name}/collections/{channel}/{url_title}}" class="perma_link" />
    </div>
   {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
{/if}
{if segment_4 == ''}
<div id="gallery-t-group" class="rsMinW single">
   {exp:channel:entries channel="ss14" dynamic="no"}
      <div class="portfolio load-slide">
        <img data-rsh="400" class="rsImg {dimension} root" src="{images}{url}{/images}" alt="{long_name}" />
            <div class="rsTmb"><img class="{dimension}" src="{images}{url}{/images}"></div>
            <input type="hidden" value="{path={site_short_name}/collections/{channel}/{url_title}}" class="perma_link" />
    </div>
   {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
{/if}
<div class="rsnav-container">

</div>  
</div><!--End Content-->
```

Basically the idea here is that I am trying to have a list layout if its under the url /collections/ss14 or /collections/aw14 and then when you go into the single entry itself /collections/ss14/entry-title or /collections/aw14/entry-title I would ideally need to have a different layout as it needs to be using some other parameters inside the channel entries tag.

Does anyone know a good solution to this problem as I am sure there are people who run into this problem all the time when dealing with expression engine.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of approaches to this. One tool that always proves useful when trying to serve a wide range of layouts and content from a single template is [**Switchee**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee). This will usually cover all the bases for you! Plus it's more efficient and flexible than native  conditionals.

Other approaches to play with (either in conjunction with Switchee or separately):

Use a URL segment variable in the `channel` parameter on your `channel:entries` tag. And if the different channel's have slightly different output requirements you can couple that with a conditional based on `channel_short_name`. For example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_3}" dynamic="yes" url_title="{segment_4}"}
    {if channel_short_name == "ss14"}
        {!-- ss14-specific template stuff here --}
    {/if}
    {if channel_short_name == "aw14"}
        {!-- ss14-specific template stuff here --}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And finally, you *can* use [*simple* conditionals](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#simple-conditionals) inside channel:entries tag parameters. Sometimes this can give you an added boost to flexibility that allows you to use a single template in multiple ways. For example, on an opening channel:entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_3}" 
    {if segment_4}
        dynamic="yes" url_title="{segment_4}"
    {/if}
}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

(This last example is pretty hypothetical, and meant only to illustrate how simple conditionals can be used on channel:entries parameters, so please take with a grain of salt.)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Alex, can the first one be used from one channel entry only because thats what i am trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if by "first one" you mean Switchee, then yes almost certainly. Switchee is an extremely flexible way to build conditionals.

Comment: So like I mentioned above, I have one template that acts to show the list of the entries for that channel and the single item. Is it better to use the 2nd solution for this, the second being the 2nd piece of code and the 1st being the first piece of code?

Comment: Is the list of entries paginated? If so, you will need to use Switchee (because sometimes segment_4 will hold a pagination slug, not a url_title). If you are _not_ paginating your listing then your options open up and you can use whichever approach appeals to you.

Comment: no its not paginated so I can use either then, I just got the aw14/ss14 channel short name bits muddled up as this is not what I am going to be switching

Comment: Hey Alex, this does not seem to be working for me. Trying lots of variations

Comment: It's hard to know how to help without knowing exactly what you're trying. I could be just be misunderstanding what you are asking for. If so, I'm sorry! It will be tricky (and discouraged by the rules of the site) to gather all of that through comments. I would recommend paring it down to the simplest example and pose as a new, more specific question showing what you're trying to do. Or hold out for another user to better answer this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12494/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-alex-kendrick)